# How do i make an if function for a certain co-ordinate in Python Turtle?

Tags: python, if-statement, coordinates, detection, python-turtle

I want my program to announce the winner using an if function that detects when it reaches the finish line. I've tried

if johncoolio == (-440,100): print("john wins) but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I have so far:

````
import turtle 
import random


pen1 = Turtle()
pen1.speed(0)
pen1.penup()
pen1.goto(-140,140)



for racepen in range(15):
  pen1.write(racepen, align= "center")
  pen1.right(90)
  pen1.forward(10)
  pen1.pendown()
  pen1.forward(150)
  pen1.penup()
  pen1.backward(160)
  pen1.left(90)
  pen1.forward(20)

JohnCoolio = Turtle()
JohnCoolio.shape("turtle")
JohnCoolio.color("red")
JohnCoolio.penup()
JohnCoolio.goto(-160, 100)
JohnCoolio.pendown()

TomCoolio = Turtle()
TomCoolio.shape("turtle")
TomCoolio.color("blue")
TomCoolio.penup()
TomCoolio.goto(-160, 60)
TomCoolio.pendown()

JerryCoolio = Turtle()
JerryCoolio.shape("turtle")
JerryCoolio.color("green")
JerryCoolio.penup()
JerryCoolio.goto(-160, 20)
JerryCoolio.pendown()


from random import randint

for racecontrol in range(50):
  JerryCoolio.forward(randint(5,10))
  JohnCoolio.forward(randint(5,10))
  TomCoolio.forward(randint(5,10)) ```
````

Comment: Where is your `if` block?  It is missing from your example.

Answer (score 0):

Y-coordinate isn't needed from turtles, you can use `xcor()` here.

```
John, Tom, Jerry = 0, 0, 0
while True:
    JohnCoolio.forward( randint( 5, 10 ) )
    TomCoolio.forward( randint( 5, 10 ) )
    JerryCoolio.forward( randint( 5, 10 ) )

    John = JohnCoolio.xcor()
    Tom = TomCoolio.xcor()
    Jerry = JerryCoolio.xcor()

    ##  crossed the finish line
    if John >= 140 or Tom >= 140 or Jerry >= 140: break

pen1.goto( 180, 100 ) ; pen1.write( John )
pen1.goto( 180, 60 ) ; pen1.write( Tom )
pen1.goto( 180, 20 ) ; pen1.write( Jerry )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `.pos()` method to get the turtle's current position.

```
if JohnCoolio.pos() == (-440,100):
```